# How to add namespace to XPath in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces

I tried to parse an XML file: http://www.ikea.com/pl/pl/catalog/products/30198858?type=xml&dataset=normal,parentCategories,allImages but I obtained error

> Namespace Manager or XlstContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable or user-definde function."

Code:

```
XPathDocument oXPathDocument = new XPathDocument(path);
XPathNavigator oXPathNameNavigator = oXPathDocument.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator oProductNodesIterator = oXPathNameNavigator.Select(@"/ikea-rest/products/product/items/item");
productModel.productName = oXPathNameNavigator.SelectSingleNode("name").Value;
```

I found that this error is being caused by lack of namespace so I tried to add it like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(oXPathNameNavigator.NameTable);
nameSpace.AddNamespace("ir",path);
```

Now I have new error:"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in line:

```
productModel.productName = oXPathNameNavigator.SelectSingleNode("name").Value;
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Perhaps: oXPathNameNavigator.SelectSingleNode("name").Value is equal to null?

Comment: Yes, it is null but I don't know why. In xml tag "name" has value "ABORG", so how can I change my code to obtain that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace handling always trips me up, so I had to play around for a bit to get this working right. Your big problem was that when you add a namespace, you provide the address for that namespace, not reuse the path to the xml doc itself.

```
XPathDocument oXPathDocument = new XPathDocument(path);
XPathNavigator oXPathNameNavigator = oXPathDocument.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager nameSpace = new XmlNamespaceManager(oXPathNameNavigator.NameTable);
//use the namespace address provided in the XML, not the path to the xml itself
nameSpace.AddNamespace("ir","http://www.ikea.com/v1.0");

//now you have to scope your query to the namespace you just defined, otherwise xpath will assume the node is not in a namespace
productModel.productName = oXPathNameNavigator.SelectSingleNode("//ir:ikea-rest/products/product/name", nameSpace).Value;
```

I tested this in LinqPAD and I was able to correctly get at the node you were interested in.